# how parsing soap xml in oracle 11g

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

how to parsing soap xml to to oracle 11g

and this is the response

```
<DataSet>
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Barang">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="KodeBarang" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DeskBarang" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="KodeSatuan" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DeskSatuan" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="KodeType" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DeskType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DeskCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DeskiDept" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DeskDevisi" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="JenisDev" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="attribute1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="attribute2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="attribute3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="UsrUpdt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="TglUpdt" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="TglUpdtDtl" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="rate_ppn" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="JenisAsset" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram>
        <NewDataSet>
            <Barang diffgr:id="Barang1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <KodeBarang>00478</KodeBarang>
                <DeskBarang>INDOMARET KALENDER</DeskBarang>
                <KodeSatuan>04</KodeSatuan>
                <DeskSatuan>UNIT</DeskSatuan>
                <KodeType>955</KodeType>
                <DeskType>20 X 20 X 9 CM</DeskType>
                <DeskCategory>CETAKAN OFFICE</DeskCategory>
                <DeskiDept>CETAKAN PROMOSI</DeskiDept>
                <DeskDevisi>PROC 6A CAT 1</DeskDevisi>
                <JenisDev>false</JenisDev>
                <UsrUpdt>ADMINPROC</UsrUpdt>
                <TglUpdt>26/09/2023</TglUpdt>
                <TglUpdtDtl>23/01/2015</TglUpdtDtl>
                <rate_ppn>11.00</rate_ppn>
                <JenisAsset>true</JenisAsset>
            </Barang>
            <Barang diffgr:id="Barang2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <KodeBarang>04181</KodeBarang>
                <DeskBarang>CONVEYOR BELT PU PUTIH 2 PLY </DeskBarang>
                <KodeSatuan>02</KodeSatuan>
                <DeskSatuan>PCS</DeskSatuan>
                <KodeType>13811</KodeType>
                <DeskType>*</DeskType>
                <DeskCategory>OTHERS</DeskCategory>
                <DeskiDept>GA & OTHERS</DeskiDept>
                <DeskDevisi>OTHERS</DeskDevisi>
                <JenisDev>false</JenisDev>
                <UsrUpdt>2015185573</UsrUpdt>
                <TglUpdt>26/09/2023</TglUpdt>
                <TglUpdtDtl>13/06/2017</TglUpdtDtl>
                <rate_ppn>11.00</rate_ppn>
                <JenisAsset>false</JenisAsset>
            </Barang>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

code how to parsing soap xml to oracle 11g

Comment: Please take more effort in asking your question. What did you try yourself and what do want to achieve?

Comment: XML is missing the namespace xs.